# When reusing component, my CSS doesn't get applied to it

Tags: css, reactjs, components, react-bootstrap, navigationbar

I am trying to figure out how something like this might occur. Bear with me, since the details might be a little bit sloppy.

I have a **Header Component** which simply takes up all the viewport, and then adds a **NavigationBar Component**. The Header Component works just fine in the other place I used it, but for some reason, when I tried reusing it just now, the NavigationBar inside it gets funky (**all CSS is simply gone**).

Here is the Header component that has the following styling (which works btw): **{position: relative;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;}**

```
    import React from "react";
    import NavigationBar from "../NavigationBar/NavigationBar";
    
    import "./Header.css";
    
    const Header = (props) => (
      <div className="blog-header">
        <NavigationBar />
          {props.children}
      </div>
    );
    
    export default Header;
```

My **NavigationBar is a simple React-Bootstrap Navbar** (I have decided to delete what was inside navigationItems because I don't think those matter to the problem at hand):

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Container, Navbar, Nav, NavbarBrand } from "react-bootstrap";
    import Logo from "../Logo/Logo";
    
    import "./NavigationBar.css";
    
    const navigationItems = []
    const NavigationBar = (props) => (
      <Container>
        <Navbar id="navigation" bg="transparent" variant="dark" expand="lg">
          <div className="div-brand d-flex flex-grow-1">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">
              <Logo />
            </NavbarBrand>
            <div className="w-100 text-right">
              <Navbar.Toggle data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#da-navbarNav">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </Navbar.Toggle>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Navbar.Collapse
            className="text-uppercase flex-grow-1 text-right"
            id="da-navbarNav"
          >
            <Nav className="ml-auto flex-nowrap">
              {navigationItems.map((navItem, index) => {
                return (
                  <Nav.Item key={index}>
                    <Nav.Link
                      id={navItem.id ? navItem.id : null}
                      href={navItem.path}
                      className={navItem.classes.join(" ")}
                      onClick={(event) =>
                        props.navItemClick(event, window.location.pathname, navItem)
                      }
                    >
                      {navItem.placeholder}
                    </Nav.Link>
                  </Nav.Item>
                );
              })}
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </Container>
    );
```

Navbar.css code:

```
    #navigation {
      z-index: 10;
    }
    
    #navigation .div-brand {
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-size: 0.95rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 24px;
      width: 6.4rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:active {
      color: #da3833;
    }
    
    .navbar-dark #btn-contact {
      background-color: #da3833;
      border-radius: 3px;
      text-align: center !important;
    }
    
    .navbar-dark #btn-contact:hover,
    .navbar-dark #btn-contact:active {
      color: white !important;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        text-align: right;
        margin-top: 0.2rem;
        margin-left: auto;
      }
    
      .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item {
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
      }
    
      .navbar-toggler {
        outline: none !important;
      }
    }
```

I'm currently reusing it inside this component that has as styling the following:

```
    .article-header {
      height: inherit;
      width: inherit;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
```

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
    import Header from "../../../components/Header/Header";
    
    import "./ArticlePage.css";
    
    const ArticlePage = (props) => {
      const [id, setId] = useState(null);
    
      const loadQueryParams = useCallback(() => {
        setId(props.match.params.id ? props.match.params.id : null);
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => loadQueryParams(), [loadQueryParams]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Header>
            <div
              className="article-header"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: "0.2" }}
            >
              {id}
            </div>
          </Header>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default ArticlePage;
```

If you might have an idea where this might go wrong, feel free to answer. I'm also gonna leave here how the [navigationbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgs2H.jpg) should look, and how it [rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObIrG.jpg).

If you need any more info or details please announce me! Thank you!

EDIT: as requested, here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ocfxr9)

Comment: Can you inspect the elements in your browser's devtools and confirm that the styles are there? From the pictures provided it seems to me that the `Header` is not fully expanded horizontally. It will be also helpful if you could provide a link with stackblitz demo.

Comment: Yes, I have inspected them and the styles are all there. I also added the demo you asked for. I tried to recreate the problem as much as I could. Will look in a few minutes into the horizontal expansion of Header, thank you for noticing that.

Comment: The result from the stacblitz demo looks fine. I just added a background color to the `.blog-header` to make the navbar items visible, because they are white and match with the document background and then it seems to be OK. Can you additionally inspect the `Contact` button as it is in your `rendered` screenshot - it does not have paddings. They are either overriden, or just missing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. The problem was that my "bootstrap.css" folder that contains my bootstrap theme was not being imported globally in "index.js", and instead it was inside "index.html".

To be noted: I was also using a Router to go to this new Component in which I was using Navbar, and since the css files weren't imported globally, the css wasn't there.